# What's the difference between crochet, knitting, and tunisian crochet?

Tags: crocheting, knitting, tunisian-crochet

What's the difference between crochet, knitting, and tunisian crochet?

At the end of the day it seems to me that all three crafts results in similar knitted texture fabrics. What makes the key difference(s) between these crafts, if anything?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The distinction between the crafts are the tools used and how many stitches are held at the same time.

- **Crochet** is done with a single hooked needle and typically only a few stitches are held at one time before being crocheted off.
- **Knitting** is done with two or more needles, and rows of stitches are held open before being knitted off.
- **Afghan/Tunisian crocheting** used a single hooked needle, but keeps an entire row of stitches held open on the needle.

Comment: And usually, knitted items are more stretchy than (Tunesian) crocheted ones.

Comment: I thought I'd add that you can (and must, when not working in the round) turn your work when knitting or crocheting, whereas you never turn your work when doing Tunisian crochet.